# Center three images in horizontal line

Tags: image

I want 3 img to be in a horizontal line and to be centered, pls help?

My code:
Html:

```
<div class="sidBilder">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="img/gapamatch.jpg">
            <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="img/laget18.jpg">
            <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="img/Kamratgarden.jpg">
        </div>


       </div> 
    </div>   
  </div> 
</div>
```

css:
I dont know what to write here to make it center and in a horizontal line?

Comment: Did you try to search how to 1/ put 3 img in horizontal line 2/ center img in google and try something before asking for code?

Comment: yes i have. Else i wouldnt ask

Comment: So please can you show us what do you tried? Here is an anwser for the "centered" part : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div and for the "in a horizontal line", just wrap each img in a `<div class="col-sm-4"></div>` so the 3 picture will always be in the same block, no?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it : 3 pictures with different size in one horizontale line and centered.

```css
.background {
 background-color : lightpink;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row background">
          <div class="col-4 wrapper">
            <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 wrapper">
            <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="https://picsum.photos/300/400">
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 wrapper">
            <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="https://picsum.photos/500/200">
          </div>
       </div> 
    </div>   
  </div> 
</div>
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really, when i test this my 3 img is just on the left side on top of each other

Comment: Do you add the html block around each image? And do you have some other css in your side that could be a problem?

Comment: this is the only css i have beside the one being posted here: .logoText{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive;
    font-size:20px;
    color:blue;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #EEEEEE;
    padding-top:40px;
    
}

Comment: Ok so it shouldn't be a problem, to make it works check : 1/ Do you have  a block around your picture? 2/ Do you use bootstrap4? Because `col-4` doesn't exist before I think, so maybe you should change it for the right class according to your bootstrap version

Comment: How do i know if i use bootstrap4? I am a beginner in this so i need a little help :(

Comment: I saw you use "col-sm-12", it's from bootstrap no? Check in your <head></head> balise after the begin of your <Doctype> when you load the bootstrap lib, you should have the version ! If you use it with a CDN you should just click the link and you should have the information